# Why I get Unsuported Media Type on GET request? (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm surely missing something, because most questions around 415 error are referring to POST requests.
In this case, this is a very simple GET request, which works when I enumerate all action parameters, but if I create a simple DTO to contain all of these, I start receiving a 415 error.

I'm calling the api with https://localhost:555/some/test?field1=aaa&field2=1

This works:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("Test")]
        public SomeResponse GetSomeResponse(string field1, int field2)
        {
            return new SomeResponse(field1, field2);
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("Test")]
        public SomeResponse GetSomeResponse(SomeRequest request)
        {
            return new SomeResponse(request.Field1, request.Field2);
        }
    }


    public class SomeRequest
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public int Field2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeResponse
    {
        public Someresponse(string field1, int field2)
        {
            Field1 = field1;
            Field2 = field2;
        }

        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public int Field2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller class is only using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

When I try to use SomeRequest class, the API answers "415 - Unsuported Media Type"

The only difference is the way to receive the values, I'm not switching from uri to body (which could be json or plain text, etc.)
But since I'm not using the body, I can't understand which media-type it is referring to

My startup class is the same as the WeatherForecast, created with the project template ASP.NET Core Web API, with Visual Studio 2022, .Net6

Comment: Have you tried a custom route handler?

Comment: Url is not enough. Can you show the whole request pls. Are you using httpclient or Postman?

Comment: @serge url is enough in this case because OP is asking about HTTP GET

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thank you, but I was asking a post owner.

Comment: @Serge, I'm using Postman, but it also works by just putting the url in the browser

Comment: I am asing it because I just tested your api using net 6 and Postman and I didn' t notice any problems. Can you show your controller header too , pls? and  someresponse class

Comment: @Serge, edited to include the controller header part... after some tries, it works if I add [FromUri] to public SomeResponse GetSomeResponse([FromUri] SomeRequest request). I thought [FromUri] would not be useful since it was not mentioned in the docs that I was reading

Comment: @zameb Thanks, but could you pls include "using" section of the controller code too

Comment: @Serge It is only using using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, referring to Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0

Comment: @zameb Where [fromuri] from if you are using net6? Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc  doesn't contain it. Can you show your startup or program code pls too?

Comment: @zameb check your project file and remove this assembly if it is there. It should be included already in net6

Comment: My bad, it is [FromQuery], my answer is updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a possible solution is to specify [FromQuery]:

```
public SomeResponse GetSomeResponse([FromQuery] SomeRequest request)
```

Tho, I am not very happy with this as reaction to "Unsuported Format", so, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: From Query works fine for me (I've upvoted). The issue is that now even if the caller was to use `POST` then they would still be forced to provide these parameters as query arguments, but the API hasn't precluded post so that creates an ambiguous implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Foster has a great writeup on this in [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET 6.0 Minimal APIs](https://benfoster.io/blog/minimal-apis-custom-model-binding-aspnet-6/)

I haven't tried it myself yet but adding this `TryParse` method to your `SomeRequest` type might help:

```
static bool TryParse(string? value, IFormatProvider? provider, out T parameter)
```

---

Generally I try not to bind objects to `HttpGet` because standard object serialization uses characters that have other meanings in standard URL routing and therefore need to be escaped in the url, which just over complicates the server and the client implementation.

I support the concept for common complex type style structures like `Point` that might be reused thought you application in many controllers and endpoints, but to create an object wrapper for each request would be ludicrous, that is a common client side technique in generated clients but we try to avoid that on the server-side.

I recommend against binding objects as GET parameters as it is a non-standard style of code that introduces a level of technical debt to the solution both in terms of API management and client implementation.

Even if you use custom binders or route handlers these solutions end up being a lot more custom code than it would have been to use primitive parameters and map them to your preferred type implementation in the first line of your endpoint method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that is not an standard way of work. Given that, I will not over-complicate it and will use unwrapped parameters. I also tried with the TryParse method but it complained about not having a parameter with the same name of the class... so, I'll fight that on the POST/PUT implementations if needed

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `HttpGetAttribute` to bind the request to query string parameters and specifically scope the requests so that only `GET` is allowed:

```
[HttpGet("Test")]
public SomeResponse GetSomeResponse2(SomeRequest request)
{
    return new SomeResponse(request.Field1, request.Field2);
}
```

It is subtle but since .Net 5 (when FromUriAttribute was replaced and the various OData and MVC routing mechanisms were combined into a common pipeline) we are encouraged to use `HttpGetAttribute` (Or the other *Http Method* variants) instead of `RouteAttribute` as a way of minimising the configuration.

---

This code has similar functionality to the [answer provided by @Zameb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726414/1690217) but it prevents users from attempting to use `POST` to access this endpoint. `[FromQuery]` creates a controller that even when a JSON object is `POST`ed to the endpoint the parameters are specifically mapped to the Query Parameters.